# Необходимо объеденить несколько текстовых файлов в один с помощью команды cat

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Необходимо объеденить несколько текстовых файлов в один с помощью команды cat. Постоянно выдает ошибку доступа. Использовать команду с помощью sudo пробовал, выдает такую же ошибку permission denied. Как обойти это? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 2):

Перенаправление ввода вывода (Т.е. `>`) выполняет текущий интерпретатор, у которого прав на запись судя по всему нет. Надо запустить с помощью sudo интерпретатор с нужными привилегиями. И отдать выполняемую команду с перенаправлением ему.

```
sudo sh -c 'cat a.txt b.txt > big.txt'
```

Comment: ну и ещё один хрестоматийный вариант: `cat a.txt b.txt | sudo tee big.txt`